# I think my friend was wrongfully fired

Tags: human-resources

A couple of weeks ago my friend was forced to take a week off because management thought she "was mentally unfit to continue the week." They forced her to get a doctor's note from her family doctor (which is in Chatham) and then when she got it, they told her that they believed the note was fake and that she would no longer be able to work with us.

Is this wrongful dismissal? Does she have a labour board case?

Comment: What Chatham? There is one in the UK, US, Austrialia. Probably other countries too

Comment: Is the job worth fighting for? Even if your friend won the case would your friend want to go back to the job

Answer (score 6):

It's impossible for us to say if your friend has a case or not. However based on what you have said it would be worth consulting a lawyer.

First if the company told your friend to stay off work then they should not require any documentation. It's their choice and there is nothing to justify. In that position I would respond "If you think I'm not fit to work you don't need a note. If you think I might be fit to work I'm happy to restart work."

Second doctor notes are trivial to verify. You phone the doctor and ask if they wrote the note.

If your friend did forge the note that's probably enough reason for firing. But you really need a lawyer for this.